# Cloned Linux Mint Root parition to a new disk - won't boot

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted, dd

I used gparted and dd to clone a failing drive's root & swap partitions to a new drive.

First I used gparted to copy and paste the root partition into a larger partition, gparted said it resized the FS to fit the new larger partition, I then did the same with the swap partition but kept it the same size. The UUID's on the new drive are exactly the same for both the root partition and the swap partition.

Then I removed the old drive and tried to boot the new one and it didn't work, so I then plugged the old drive back in and used dd to copy the root partition from the old drive to the new one, it still won't boot.

The old drive still boots fine.

Looking elsewhere, I've seen I have to update grub and fstab with the new UUID's but they are exactly the same so it should just work, right?

What is the problem here?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the `parted -l` [output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120223/66388) (or a similar one)...

Comment: @Paul Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device

Comment: @jack - seems like you must have cloned the partitions, but not the boot sector?

Comment: @Paul I see that it's quite easy to do, my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: **Only with an MBR**  `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` (see more [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/)) else you can use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), give it a look [here too](http://lifehacker.com/5891933/the-best-disk-cloning-app-for-linux).